# link_to block not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I'm using a series of `link_to` blocks to create buttons in my application.  However I'm finding that these links don't end up working.  As I mouse-over the button, it recognizes the link, the correct url displays in the lower left-hand corner in firefox, but when I click, nothing happens. Nothing comes up in my terminal or development log either.

**My code is as follows:**

```
<%= link_to new_folder_path do%>
    <div class="btn btn-default add-button add_fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add Folder</div>
<% end %>
```

**This renders the following html:**

```
<li>
  <a href="/folders/new">
    <div class="btn btn-default add-button add_fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add Folder</div>
  </a>
</li>
```

I should also note that if I just type the standard link in without the do block, it runs just fine:

```
<li><%= link_to "test", new_folder_path %></li>
```

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @Pavan I suppose I should be a bit more verbose on that: It's not directing me to the link.  As I mouse-over the button, it recognizes the link, the correct url displays in the lower left-hand corner in firefox, but when I click nothing happens.  Nothing comes up in my terminal or development log either.

Comment: That should work. But, try adding `display: block` to that `a` element. Also, run the markup through the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/), maybe you have some errors which are causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had dropped a class into my div that prevented the link from rendering (`add_fields` was the class).  Profoundly unsatisfying answer it is what it is.  Thanks to anyone who took the time to give me a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>Add Folder".html_safe, new_folder_path, class: 'btn btn-default add-button add_fields'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better using [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) for the buttons -

> Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options.

So instead of your `link_to`, you'd be able to use:

```
<%= button_to "Add Folder", new_folder_path, class: "btn btn-default add-button add_fields glyphicon glyphicon-plus" %>
```

As a sidenote, if you're trying to style elements *inside* an `<a>` tag, you're going to have problems. You'll be much better styling the `<a>` tag itself, or not at all.

As such, the issue you're getting could probably be resolved using the following:

```
<%= link_to "Add Folder", new_folder_path, class: "btn btn-default add-button add_fields glyphicon glyphicon-plus" %>
```

--

*Icons*

I know Bootstrap includes `Glyphicons`. If they're anything like [`ionIcons`](http://ionicons.com/), they'll work by prepending the glyph with a `:before` pseudo class.

If this is the case, you *don't* need a separate `<span>` element to encapsulate them; just add the class to your link/button and the `:before` should be prepended.

*Of course*, if you want to style the span inside the link, you'll have to use the `link_to` block; however you need ensure you encase your text in the `span` instead of having it with no content.